# Remove gap between buttons and rounded corners

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a this jpanel with 2 buttons inside

[image]

I want to remove the space between the buttons, and remove the rounded corners so it looks something like this

[image]

Right now I'm using `GridLayout(1,2,0,0)`

**Edit:**

```
    JButton englishBtn = new JButton();
    JButton polishBtn = new JButton();

    Font verdana = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11);
    englishBtn.setText("EN");
    englishBtn.setFont(verdana);
    englishBtn.setFocusable(false);
    englishBtn.setBackground(new Color(5, 74, 127));
    englishBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    polishBtn.setText("PL");
    polishBtn.setFont(verdana);
    polishBtn.setFocusable(false);
    polishBtn.setBackground(new Color(153, 0, 0));
    polishBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JPanel langPanel = new JPanel();
    GridLayout langLayout = new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0);
    langPanel.setLayout(langLayout);
    langPanel.add(englishBtn);
    langPanel.add(polishBtn);
```

Comment: Please post your code..

Answer (score 2):

Try using `setHgap` and `setVgap` to zero.

This documentation may help you -

[http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#setHgap(int)](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#setHgap%28int%29)

Comment: I set it in the constructor `new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0)` but the gap still shows.

Comment: Dont use it in constructor - Try `langLayout.setHgap(0);` and `langLayout.setVgap(0);`

Comment: Setting with langLayout.setHgap(-5); and langLayout.setVgap(0) works for the gap

Answer (score 1):

Take a class that implments Border interface as follows

> `class RoundedBorder implements Border {
>
>           int radius;
>
>           RoundedBorder(int radius) {
>
>               this.radius = radius;
>
>           }
>
>           public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
>
>               return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
>
>           }
>
>           public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
>
>               return true;
>
>           }
>
>           public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int     height) {
>
>               g.drawRoundRect(x,y,width-3,height-3,radius,radius);
>
>               g.setColor(Color.red);
>
>               c.setForeground(Color.red);
>
>           }
>
>       }`

Now on the property of your button i.e. button.set "b1.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(50));
" pass the radius that you want in a button as argument to RoundedBorder(radius).

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Please correct the formatting, spacing and indentation of your answer.